# How do I disable ES Module Error's in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules, commonjs

I have recently made the switch to use Bun as my JS Runtime of choice, and in the switch the relevance of ES Modules vs CommonJS became a moot point because Bun doesn't acknowledge either and it all just works.  Unfortunately VSCode doesn't seem to agree and whenever I do something that would work in Bun, but not for Node.JS, it gives me errors such as:

[image]

and

[image]

I acknowledge that I could simply use @ts-ignore, but that would get out of hand rather quickly.  I want to know if there is something I can do to my TSConfig file or my VSCode settings that would rid me of these ESM vs CommonJS errors.

Edit: Changing the package.json to `"type": "module"` produces many more errors than it fixes.

Comment: Which errors do you get when changing your package.json file to `"type": "module"`?

Comment: @Valentin All of my import statements then require me to add ".js" to the end of them, and that is something I would like to avoid if at all possible

Comment: Have you tried setting [`moduleResolution`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution) to `bundler` in `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: That fixed my problem, thank you so much!

Comment: I posted an answer which explains a bit more what each option does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our exchange in the comments section, you should do the following:

1. Modify your `package.json` file to add/modify:

```json
"type": "module"
```

2. Modify your `tsconfig.json` file to add/modify:

```json
"moduleResolution": "bundler"
```

#### Explanation

1. `"type": "module"` in `package.json` tells Typescript to interpret `.js` files as ES Modules (instead of CommonJS by default).
2. [`"moduleResolution": "bundler"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution) in `tsconfig.json` tells Typescript that your bundler is going to take care of the relative import paths and will not require the `.js` extension that Node.js needs in ESM mode.